# How to work with PHP add to Cart using Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, cart

I have a code for filterable audio files, how can I add add-to-cart functionality?

My index.php file:

https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff432c06f57

and my fetch_data.php file,

https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff436697ed2

Here if I click **add to playlist** button the alert was shown based on the hello.php file [ just echo message ], here how can I save my id and name into the hello.php page like cart page, if I click add to playlist button I need my id and name save into the hello.php page.

Current Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

on your Button onClick, add new function like addCart()

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="padding: 5px 83px 5px 83px;" onclick="addCart(<?php echo $row['voice_id']; ?>); " >Add to PlayList </button>
```

then your script should be like to call ajax

```
<script>
function addCart(id) {

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'hello.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data : {id: id}, // pass id to the php
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);


            }
        });
}
```

and in your hello.php

```
<?php

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 //code to save it to databse table
?>
```

Comment: After add the line : https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff4dbb21ba1 my output : https://snag.gy/yPif71.jpg how to solve the issue?

Comment: ok, here you already wrote your code inside php script so you don't need to open php tags again `onclick="addCart(<?php echo $row["voice_id"]; ?>); "`

instead. just use `onclick="addCart('. $row["voice_id"] .' ); "`

Comment: alert working good, if i try with id and name showing to cart php page, my workout   https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff8b11c8661

Comment: above code consists, button & ajax & cart.php page. If i click button nothing will happen.

Comment: Ok, i hve updated this lines on your code here. https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff436697ed2  please visit and see the changes i made

Comment: now i click button : https://snag.gy/NFRaci.jpg  and ajax is : https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff9691208da, alert working. Here how can i send to another php file, my another php file is cart.php, how to get vaoice_id and display in cart.php file : https://www.pastiebin.com/5cff9757eaab8

Comment: put `$id = $_POST['id'];` in your cart.php file here you will get the passed id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194755/discussion-between-zus-and-sanjun-dev).